# Is it possible to rotate Viewport3D around any of the three axes?

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation, viewport3d

I know that a `ModelVisual3D` can be rotated around any axis via `AxisAngleRotation3D`, but is it possible to do the same with Viewport3D that contains 9 `ModelVisual3D`s, so they are rotated together as if they are one object.. for example I can do this with `ModelVisual3D`:

```
<Viewport3D.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Viewport3D.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                  Storyboard.TargetName="myVerticalRotation"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                  From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:10"
                  RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                  Storyboard.TargetName="myHorizontalRotation"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                  From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:9"
                  RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Viewport3D.Triggers>
```

but this presumes that `Viewport3D` contains only one `ModelVisual3D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by containing all `GeometryModel3D` objects inside a `Model3DGroup` inside `ModelUIElement3D` inside `ContainerUIElement3D`, and then we're able to define the `RotateTransform3D` in `ContainerUIElement3D.Transform`:

```
 <ContainerUIElement3D>
                    <ModelUIElement3D>
                        <Model3DGroup>
                            <GeometryModel3D>...</GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D>...</GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D>...</GeometryModel3D>
                        </Model3DGroup>
                    </ModelUIElement3D>
                    <ContainerUIElement3D.Transform>
                      <Transform3DGroup>
                        <RotateTransform3D >
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D  x:Name="myHorizontalRotation" Angle="142.884" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                     </Transform3DGroup>
                   </ContainerUIElement3D.Transform>
            </ContainerUIElement3D>
```